# Accessing JSON data via jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following is returned through the variable `data`.

```
{"success":0,"errors":[],"field_errors":{"title":"This field is required.","url_title":"This field is required.","field_id_9":"This field is required.","field_id_229":"This field is required.","testimonial_import_id":"This field is required.","testimonial_display":"This field is required."},"entry_id":null,"url_title":null,"channel_id":"4"}
```

I am unable to access individual items.

I have tried:

```
data.success
data[0]
data[0].success
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: `String` or `Object` ?

Comment: How would I tell? I am returning it directly into a function, so i think object.

Comment: `console.log(typeof data)`

Comment: `JSON.parse(data).success`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON string using **[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** method for converting it to JavaScript object.

```
JSON.parse(data).success
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue. I will mark your answer as correct as soon as I can.